# DreamFactory connection string failing connecting to RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, database-connection, connection-string

I've been trying to set up a Service in DreamFactory to connection to my RDS SQL Server 2008 Instance and it keeps failing with the following error.

```
{
    "error": [
        {
            "context": null,
            "message": "Failed to launch service &quot;xxxxx&quot;: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.",
            "code": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

am I missing some parameter to allow the connection to work? I've tried it with and without the port number and I've added the DreamFactory IP address into the Security Group in RDS (23.23.78.250)

[image: SQL Connection]

I'm not sure what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to happen when using MSSQL Server Express instead of Standard or Enterprise edition on Amazon RDS.  You can use a MSSQL Express edition by using hostname\SQLEXPRESS where SQLEXPRESS is the instance name for non Amazon RDS instances.

Check here for progress on this bug: https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/issues/17